# Создание элементов программно

Tags: java, android, android-layout

подскажите как я могу создать элемент RelativeLayout c с вложенным в него TextView программно? Сам элемент я сделал, но вот не могу сделать атрибуты

```
android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"


LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) indViewById(R.id.LL);
RelativeLayout relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(getApplicationContext());
// Вот здесь не уверен, правильно ли сделал?
// android:background="#ССС34А"
relativeLayout.setBackground(Drawable.createFromPath("#ССС34А"));
relativeLayout.setPadding(1,1,1,1);
relativeLayout.setLayoutParams(
   new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
   LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
   LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
)
);
linearLayout.addView(relativeLayout);
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый нажав на галочку слева.

Answer (score 0):

Если у вас два данных тега используется:

```
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
```

То можно их заменить на один:

```
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
```

Смысл я думаю будет тот же что и с двумя тегами выше. Дальше вам нужно только применить этот тег и тег отступа программно:

```
View tv= findViewById(R.id.tv);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = 
    (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)positiveButton.getLayoutParams();
layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
relativeParams.setMargins(0, 0, 5, 0); // left, top, right, bottom
tv.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

Вот есть подобные вопросы [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4979212/how-to-create-a-relativelayout-programmatically-with-two-buttons-one-on-top-of-t) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3985787/android-relativelayout-programmatically-set-centerinparent). Так же у текстового поля можно установить расположение таким способом:

```
textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
```